# android app: aligning imageviewS in center horizontally

Tags: java, android, imageview

So I'm messing with `imageviews` and I am able to align a single `imageview` in the center horizontally with the following code:

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

Now my main problem is that I have X `imageviews` and when I align them all like that and then use the `android:layout_toRightOf=""`, they just start from the middle.

What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap them in a horizontal LinearLayout that is centred in your RelativeLayout

Comment: You didn't figure that out in 3 years? :P

Answer (score 0):

a fast solution you will align the first to the left then the next imageviews `toRightOf=`
(delete `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` from your layout)

Comment: yeah, but I want it all centered :)